# Trying to update a row (table) using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

Im trying without success to update a row in a table. I mean, when i click on "update" button it goes to another page and i got the previous "values" so i can edit them and finally click on "save".

**But it is not working in my program :/..When i click on "edit" button it goes to another page and i only have the previous values of a single field (Field subject). AND when i click on save it does not update anything, it creates a new row.**

Here is my code:
The index file, here i put the button "edit".

```
                        <a href='".site_url('Home/editar')."/$record->id'> 
                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDIT</button></a>
```

My controller file, with the function "editar" and "saveupdate":

```
        public function editar($id){
        $data['carreras'] = $this->Crudmodel->get_carreras();
        $data['record']=$this->Crudmodel->get_id_row($id);
        $this->load->view('editar',$data);
        }
          public function saveupdate(){
            $id=$this->input->post("txtid");
            $txtcarr=$this->input->post("txtcarr");
            $txtmat=$this->input->post("txtmat");
            $txtdesc=$this->input->post("txtdesc");
            $txtcarga=$this->input->post("txtcarga");

        $this->Crudmodel->saveup($txtcarr,$txtmat,$txtdesc,$txtcarga);
         $this->db->where("id", $id);
        redirect('Home/index');

    }
```

The Crudmodel with the function "saveup"

```
    public function saveup($txtcarr, $txtmat, $txtdesc, $txtcarga){

      $data=array(
        'carrera_id'=>$txtcarr,
        'nombre'=>$txtmat,
        'descripcion'=>$txtdesc,
        'carga_horaria'=>$txtcarga

    );

      $this->db->update('materias', $data);

}
```

Here is the get_id_row from crudmodel:

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgqPx.png)

Finally, the "editar" file which contains all the fields.

```
<body>

<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


    <h2 align="center">UPDATE SUBJECTS</h2>
    <form method="post" action='<?php echo site_url('Home/saveupdate'); ?>'>
    <tr>

        <td><input type="text" hidden name="txtid" value="<?php echo $record->id ?>"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <select name="txtcarr">
                <?php foreach($carreras as $item):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->nombre;?></option>
                 <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Subject : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtmat" value="<?php echo $record->nombre ?>"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Description : </td>
        <td><textarea name="txtdesc" value="<?php echo $record->descripcion ?>"></textarea></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Hours : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtcarga"/></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>

    </tr>


        <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="300">



        </table>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Do not understand what should i do :S

Comment: $this->db->where('ID', $id); add following line in model.

Comment: You mean this?
https://i.gyazo.com/79a750fc143b061b69e6fbea6109dec9.png
It is not working :/

Comment: Yes but parse ID from controller.

Comment: What?, dont get it pal:S

Comment: First make array in controller than parse array to model. And parse ID to model.

Comment: I did this:
$this->Crudmodel->saveup($txtcarr,$txtmat,$txtdesc,$txtcarga, $id);

And finally put this in the model:
$this->db->where("id", $id);
$this->db->update('materias', $data);

But now it does not add a new row BUT it does not save changes :/

Comment: EDIT: it saves properly now but icannot get the previous information of the rest of the fields :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Rushabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6921231/rushabh-shah) thinks you should pass your `$id` with your data to the model like this:

```
$this->Crudmodel->saveup($txtcarr,$txtmat,$txtdesc,$txtcarga, $id);
```

and in your **model** you can:

```
$this->db->where("id", $id);
$this->db->update('materias', $data);
```

and don't forget to remove your where condition in the **controller**;

## Edit:

your `get_id_row()` function needs to be:

```
public function get_id_row($id){
  $query = $this->db->get_where('your_table_name', array('id' => $id));
  return $query->row();
}
```